# Ejabberd 2.1.13 - ejabberdctl isn't working from terminal on MAC

Tags: macos, ejabberd

I have ejabberd 2.1.13 installed locally on OS X. It's working.
Now I'm trying to migrate to MySQL. The problem is I cant launch any command using
Ejabberd ctl utility.

```
MacBook:bin user$ ejabberdctl export2odbc
-bash: ejabberdctl: command not found
```

Server is running at that moment.

Thanks

Comment: Solved.
I have to use ./ejabberdctl when I'm in 'bin' directory on MacOS.